# Magento Price filter

Tags: magento

In my site the filter is showing the price: Rs 0.00-Rs 1.00.

I need to sort the price by automatically fetching the minimum value.

Following is the code from filter.phtml, please help.

```
   if(!function_exists("_displayDropdown")){
        function _displayDropdown($atts,$displayitemcount,$new_attributeName){
            echo '<select id="layered-select" class="select" name="layered-select" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex > 0) location.href=this[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
            echo '<option selected="selected">'.$new_attributeName.'</option>';
            foreach ($atts->getItems() as $_item){
                echo '<option value="'.$_item->getUrl().'">';
                echo $_item->getLabel();
                if($displayitemcount){
                    echo ' ('.$_item->getCount().')';
                }
                echo '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }

    switch ($attributeName) {
        case 'Shoe Size':
        case 'Overthreshold':
            _displayDropdown($this,$displayitemcount,$new_attributeName);
            break;

        default:
            _displayOrderedlist($this,$displayitemcount);
            break;
```

}

Comment: Could you add some code and tell us where you are having this issue

Comment: I fix this issue by changing the settings in backend of magento admin panel. Set the price attribute to (Use In Layered Navigation="yes".)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fix this issue by changing the settings in backend of magento admin panel. Set the price attribute to (Use In Layered Navigation="yes".)